# bootstrap buttons without space nest to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I create two buttons with full page width below each other on large screen and on small screen next to each other ?

This working, but there is no space between the buttons.

Thanks

Large screen
[image: Large screen]

Small screen

[image: Small screen]
Thanks

```
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-lg col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mb-1" BackColor="#469784" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ForeColor="#ffffff" runat="server" Text="BUTTON 1"  />
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-lg col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mb-1" BackColor="#469784" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ForeColor="#ffffff" runat="server" Text="BUTTON 2" />
                </div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

For placing buttons next to each other:

```
  <div class="button-box col-lg-12">
            <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
            <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
   </div>
```

use this css for adjusting the width:

```
.button-box {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:20px;
 }
 
.btn-info {
    width: 49%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #17a2b8;
    border-color: #17a2b8;
}
```

The above code will help in creating two buttons placed next to each other and works on both small, medium and large devices.

However, if you wish to use your code and just add slight distance between the two buttons then try adding margin for the button.

This can be done by using css such as :

```
.button{ //change to your button class name
margin:1%;
}
```